# Database schema to store messages sent and messages received to the same person

Tags: database, postgresql, relational-database

I'm trying to come up with a schema for storing messages from an SMS app. It needs to store the messages sent from sender and the messages sent to that sender. If someone could tell me the best way to do this, it's highly appreciated. I'm using Postgresql if that makes any difference.

Comment: `to,from,message` and whatever more you need? Possibly add an index to `to` & `from` to be able to look them up quickly.

Comment: @Wrikken Normalize the phone numbers for `to` and `from`, to; can't imagine anything else would be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do brievly:

Table contact:

```
CREATE TABLE contact
(
  contact_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  contact_name character varying,
  contact_phone_number character varying(40),
  CONSTRAINT contact_pkey PRIMARY KEY (contact_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

And the sms table:

```
CREATE TABLE sms
(
  msg_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('message_msg_id_seq'::regclass),
  sender_id bigint,
  receiver_id bigint,
  msg_content text,
  CONSTRAINT message_pkey PRIMARY KEY (msg_id),
  CONSTRAINT sms_receiver_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (receiver_id)
      REFERENCES contact (contact_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT sms_sender_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sender_id)
      REFERENCES contact (contact_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
    )
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with two tables:

user table: `id, name, {other info about your user}`

messages table: `id, sender, receiver, message, {other info about message}`